# How to Package files using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jekyll

I have three separate files, and I would like to have a script that would install the below files in the local folder

**Package Items**

https://gitlab.com/darkout/builder/-/raw/master/_data/do-hero-content.yml
https://gitlab.com/darkout/builder/-/raw/master/_includes/do-hero-content.html
https://gitlab.com/darkout/builder/-/raw/master/_sass/modules/do-hero-content.scss

**Sample code example**

`install do-hero`

Should install the above three files in the local in the following folders

**expected output: to have the files in the local below folder**

local > /_data/do-hero-content.yml

local > /_includes/do-hero-content.html

local > /_sass/modules/do-hero-content.scss

Could someone advise me what the best way to execute this is?

Thanks
Shovan

Answer (score 0):

You can write a ruby script called `install` that downloads these files (Calling curl or [HTTPX](https://honeyryderchuck.gitlab.io/httpx/wiki/home.html)), then use [FileUtils](https://rubyapi.org/o/fileutils) to copy them to the location you wanted:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

if ARGV[0] == 'do-hero'
  # Write code to download these 3 files and copy to folders you want
end
```